# Unable to call String from OnTimeSetListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I added a TimePicker to my App. The selected time is displayed corecctly in the TextView, but I can't call the String later to send it to the Server.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mArrivalTimepicker = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            String ArrivalTimeString = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            TextView ArriavalTime = findViewById(R.id.arrival_time_tv);
            ArriavalTime.setText(ArrivalTimeString);
        }
    };
}
```

When I later try to call it, it says 'cannot resolve Symbol 'ArrivalTimeString'.

```
public void addMessage() {
    String arrivalTime = ArrivalTimeString;
}
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Edit:
I now declared the String global. I can call the String now, but it's Value ist still empty.

```
String ArrivalTimeString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mArrivalTime = findViewById(R.id.arrival_time_tv);

mArrivalTimepicker = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            ArrivalTimeString = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
        }
    };
mArrivalTime.setText(ArrivalTimeString);
}
```

So after I select a time it still won't display the selected time.

Solution:
I still call the `.setText` within the `.OnTimeSetListener`. To use the String later on, I use

```
ArrivalTimeString = mArrivalTime.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

String arrivalTime = ArrivalTime.getText().toString(); 
If assigned string and displayed string is same.
Never declare a view inside any time or date picker. It should be in onCreate() method otherwise you wont get the data from that textview outside your time picker.

Answer (score 0):

String ArrivalTimeString = hourOfDay + ":" + minute; 
Above line should be
String ArrivalTimeString = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);
Also you can not use String ArrivalTimeString in other functions as you are declaring it in inline class. Best is make it field/class variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
String ArrivalTimeString;
TextView ArriavalTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArriavalTime = findViewById(R.id.arrival_time_tv);

    mArrivalTimepicker = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            ArrivalTimeString = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            ArriavalTime.setText(ArrivalTimeString);
        }
    };
}
```

If you want to reuse your ArrivalTimeString outside of the `onTimeSet()` method, then you should change it into a global variable instead of a local variable.

When you created your ArrivalTimeString inside of `onTimeSet()`, you're creating it as a local variable. A local variable will only live until the end of the method that you declare it in, so once you've reached the end of `onTimeSet()`, the ArrivalTimeString variable is already gone.

As such, you'll get the `cannot resolve Symbol 'ArrivalTimeString'` error when you're trying to use ArrivalTimeString in other methods.

This is because your ArrivalTimeString simply doesn't exist anymore because the method it was created in has already finished.

Therefore, the fix for this is to **declare** the ArrivalTimeString variable as a global variable. By placing the variable outside of methods, you're making the 'life' of the variable exist for as long as the class is still alive.

Also, you should avoid using `findViewById()` inside of your `OnTimeSetListener()`. Finding a view by Id can be an expensive process, so if you're going to be accessing the TextView often, you should also declare ArriavalTime outside of `OnTimeSet()`. This avoids your app from constantly searching for a View every time the Time is set.

P.S. I believe you might have a typo for the TextView ArriavalTime.

Comment: Thank you. I now declared the String as global, just like in your code, but I am Still unable to call the String outside of my `OnTimeSetListener()` . So when I try to set the text outside of the `OnTimeSet()` it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Did you make sure to delete the 'String' keyword from `String ArrivalTimeString = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;` ?

Comment: Yes. Apparently the String value is still not set as supposed to. When I use the `setText()` ouside of the `OnTimeSet()` the text simply doesn't change.

Comment: Please show the code related to the other `setText()` that you're calling from outside of `onTimeSet()`.

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks for your patience btw :)

Comment: I've looked at your edit and the reason why it's not being updated after a time is picked is because you've moved `mArrivalTime.setText(ArrivalTimeString);` outside of the `onTimeSet()` method. Basically, you're using `setText()` does run, but it's running only inside of your `onCreate()` which ended before the user can even pick a time. Therefore, your `setText()` is simply setting the default value of `ArrivalTimeString` which is `""`. Your `onTimeSet()` only runs when a user has picked a time, but all that happens then is it'll update `ArrivalTimeString`.

Comment: It won't set new text to `mArrivalTime` because you don't have the code to `mArrivalTime.setText()` inside of `onTimeSet()`. It simply doesn't know to update the text, because your code to update text is inside of `onCreate()`, but `onCreate()` only gets called ONCE which is when an Activity starts. So if you want to update your TextView with the new time, I suggest putting the TextView back inside `onTimeSet()`.